# Resolution since installing 16.04 LTS

Tags: support

I asked this question yesterday but it has disappeared?
Maybe I did something wrong ..... anyway:

I installed 16.04 on Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo Mobile V5535 and ticked all the boxes re updates etc...

Overwriting Vista.

I now have a screen resolution of 640x800 and cannot navigate to RHS of screen.

Please note I'm a beginner with Ubuntu, so you can treat me like a child :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your question hasn't disappeared, it's right here:

https://askubuntu.com/q/795597/85695

This site, (meta.askubuntu.com) is only for discussing how the main site (askubuntu.com) works, not for actual Ubuntu questions. Your question is on the main site, right where you left it.

Comment: Ah, I see ... Thank you for your prompt reply.